# Flask can't handle json data in ajax GET request

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I try to send jQuery AJAX request to my flask server :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/get',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:"application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ subject : "gpu",
                    filter : {
                        ids: [2, 3]
                        }
                    }),
            success: function (data) {
                console.debug(data);
            }
        });
```

And then I wait for a response from the server. Server part looks like this:

```
@api.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def get():
    response = None
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        response = do_some_magic(data)
    except Exception as e:
        respond = {'state': 'error', 'data': e.message}
    finally:
        return json.dumps(respond)
```

So, this combination doesn't work. `request` has only args field = `ImmutableMultiDict([('{"subject":"gpu","filter":{"ids":[2,3]}}', u'')])` and `json` field = `None`.

But when in ajax request I set `type: 'GET'` and in flask get method `methods=['GET']`, server starts to handle requests correctly.

So, it would not be a real issue, but then I tried to send a GET request with postman utility. It's request:

```
GET /get HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1d94d81c-7d93-4cf6-865a-b8e3e28278c1
{
    "subject": "gpu",
    "filter": {
        "ids": [
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

And flask code worked with `methods=['GET']`. So the question is, what can cause such behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Yeah, but the question is, why GET requests from postman are processed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>   Data to be sent to the server. 
>   It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

If `processData` is set to `false`, it means that the `data` string is still appended to the URL, just without some processing.

This may be due to the behaviour of `XMLHttpRequest.send()`

> send() accepts an optional parameter which lets you specify the request's body; this is primarily used for requests such as PUT. If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to null.